# C#でComboBoxの値に応じてレイアウトを変更したい

Tags: c#, visual-studio

C#(Visual studio2015)でComboBoxの値に応じてレイアウトを変更したいです。

xamlファイル

```
    <ComboBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding TypeCollection}"
              DisplayMemberPath="Text"
              Width="140" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
   <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="test A!" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>★１
   <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Text="test B!" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>★２
```

TypeCollectionにはAとBが選択できるようになっているのですが、
Aを選んだ時に★１、Bを選んだ時に★２のテキストを表示させたいです。

xamlでそのような条件わけができるのでしょうか？
それともCSファイル側で行うべきなのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ComboBox`には選択値に応じて変化するプロパティがいくつかありますので、そのいずれかに対する`{Binding}`を作成すれば`DataTrigger`に使用することができます。手順としては

1. `<ComboBox>`に`Name`を指定する
2. `<TextBlock>`に`<Style>`を追加する
3. `<Style.Triggers>`に`<DataTrigger>`を追加し、`Binding`に`ElementName`として`1.`を、`Path`に`Selected****`を指定する。
4. `<DataTrigger>`に`Visibility`を変更する`<Setter>`を追加する。

となり、例えば`SelectedIndex`が分かっている場合は

```
<ComboBox
    x:Name="comboBox" />
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style
            TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger
                    Binding="{Binding ElementName=comboBox, Path=SelectedIndex}"
                    Value="1">
                    <Setter
                        Property="Visibility"
                        Value="Collapsed" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
    test A!
</TextBlock>
```

のようになります。

ただ`ComboBox.ItemsSource`をバインドしているのに特定のインデックスや値を要素を想定したトリガーをビュー側に記述するのは行儀が良いとはいいがたいです。コーディング量も`DataContext`内で適切に実装した方が少なくなりますので、参考程度に考えてください。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。なんとなくイメージがつきました。Viewに書くよりも…とのアドバイスもありがとうございます。試しにトライしてみたいと思います。